# Python : Print only the results that are in a specific list

Tags: python, if-statement, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

Full code:

```py
cp1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
cp1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
cn1=[7,8,9,10,11,12]
cn2=[13,14,15,16,17,18] 
cn3=[19,20,21,22,23,24]
cn4=[25,26,27,28,29,30]
import itertools
sets = [cp1,cn1];
ks = [3,2] 
for i in itertools.product(*[itertools.combinations(set, k) for set, k in zip(sets, ks)]):
    a = i[0]+i[1]
    for i in itertools.permutations(a) :
        i_sum1 = i[0] +  i[1]
        i_sum2 = i_sum1 + i[2]
        i_sum3 = i_sum2 + i[3]
        i_sum4 = i_sum3 + i[4]
        i2_sum1 = i[1] + i[2]
        i2_sum2 = i2_sum1 + i[3]
        i2_sum3 = i2_sum2 + i[4]
        i3_sum1 = i[2] + i[3]
        i3_sum2 = i3_sum1 + i[4]
        i4_sum1 = i[3] + i[4]
        allsum =(i_sum1,  i_sum2,i_sum3,i_sum4, i2_sum1, i2_sum2, i2_sum3, i3_sum1,i3_sum2,i4_sum1)
        if (i_sum1 or  i_sum2 or i_sum3 or i_sum4 or i2_sum1 or i2_sum2 or i2_sum3 or i3_sum1 or i3_sum2 or i4_sum1) not in (cn1 or cn2 or cn3) :
            for b in itertools.product(cn4, repeat=2):
                if (b[0] and b[1]) in allsum :
                    print (i,allsum)
```

Explanation:

1. random lists

   ```py
   cp1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
   cn1=[7,8,9,10,11,12]
   cn2=[13,14,15,16,17,18] 
   cn3=[19,20,21,22,23,24]
   cn4=[25,26,27,28,29,30]
   ```
2. combination between 2 lists, using 3 elements of one and 2 of the other one for each result

   ```py
   import itertools
   sets = [cp1,cn1];
   ks = [3,2] 
   for i in itertools.product(*[itertools.combinations(set, k) for set, k in zip(sets, ks)]):
   ```
3. merging the results

   ```py
       a = i[0]+i[1]
   ```
4. permutation of the results

   ```py
       for i in itertools.permutations(a) :
   ```
5. specific sum of the permutations

   ```py
           i_sum1 = i[0] +  i[1]
           i_sum2 = i_sum1 + i[2]
           i_sum3 = i_sum2 + i[3]
           i_sum4 = i_sum3 + i[4]
           i2_sum1 = i[1] + i[2]
           i2_sum2 = i2_sum1 + i[3]
           i2_sum3 = i2_sum2 + i[4]
           i3_sum1 = i[2] + i[3]
           i3_sum2 = i3_sum1 + i[4]
           i4_sum1 = i[3] + i[4]
           allsum =(i_sum1,  i_sum2,i_sum3,i_sum4, i2_sum1, i2_sum2, i2_sum3, i3_sum1,i3_sum2,i4_sum1)
   ```

   printing only specific results:
6. avoid the the result if any of it sums are in any of the lists, cn1, cn2, or cn3:
   **(here is where I'm having problems)**

   ```py
           if (i_sum1 or  i_sum2 or i_sum3 or i_sum4 or i2_sum1 or i2_sum2 or i2_sum3 or i3_sum1 or i3_sum2 or i4_sum1) not in (cn1 or cn2 or cn3) :
   ```
7. Print only the remain results that contain 2 elements of a certain list, cn4 ***(and here)***

   ```py
           for b in itertools.product(cn4, repeat=2):
               if (b[0] and b[1]) in allsum :
                   print (i,allsum)
   ```

Output:

the first result is `(1, 2, 3, 7, 12) (3, 6, 13, 25, 5, 12, 24, 10, 22, 19)`
it shows that the 6, and the 7 parts are not working. 6ª should prevent it because it contain (13,12,24,22,19),elements of cn1, cn2 and cn3. And 7ª should prevent it because it do not contain two elements of cn4, but only one, "25".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  Any chance of condensing the question down to a [mcve] - using *fake* data to illustrate the point is OK.  Your condition isn't clear: do you want to exclude ALL of those items if ANY are `in (cn1 or cn2 or cn3)`? or do you want to exclude individual items if they are `in (cn1 or cn2 or cn3)`?

Comment: Yes, if any of those itens are in any of those lists (cn1,cn2,cn3) the whole result that contains it should be avoided. And thanks for your suggestion, i'll read it for my next posts

Answer (score 0):

Use sets to test for membership.

```
q = set(cn1)
q.update(cn2)
q.update(cn3)
# or
##q = set(itertools.chain(cn1, cn2, cn3))
# or
##q = set(n for item in (cn1, cn2, cn3) for n in item)

#fake i_sums
z = [25, 26, 27, 28, 2]
z = set(z)

#for your code
##z = set(i_sum1,  i_sum2, i_sum3, i_sum4, i2_sum1, i2_sum2, i2_sum3, i3_sum1, i3_sum2, i4_sum1)


>>> q.isdisjoint(z)
True
>>> if q.isdisjoint(z):
    print('doit')

doit
>>>
```